# Stuck on 'One man went to mow' python code

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, math

so my teacher made us do this 'one man went to mow' nursery rhyme in python, and I just can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

```
num = ['One man','Two men','Three men','Four men','Five men',
       'Six men','Seven men','Eight men','Nine men','Ten men']

for i in range(0,len(num)):
    print(num[i],'went to mow, went to mow a meadow,')
    # Check if i is greater than 0, to avoid index out of range errors
    if i > 0:
        # Loop through the previous elements in the num list
        for n in range(i-1,-1,-1):
            print(num[i],num[n],'and his dog, went to mow a meadow.')
```

The objective is to try get it to print:

'One man went to mow, went to mow a meadow
One man and his dog
Went to mow a meadow

Two men went to mow
Went to mow a meadow
Two men, one man and and his dog
Went to mow a meadow

Three men went to mow
Went to mow a meadow
Three men, two men, one man
And his dog
Went to mow a meadow

Four men went to mow
Went to mow a meadow
Four men, three men, two men, one man
And his dog
Went to mow a meadow'

basically all the way up to the 10th one. the bit im stuck on is getting it count down like "Four men, three men, two men, one man". been stuck on this for a while and would appreciate some help

Tried fixing it many different ways like changing the nested for loop to i-1, to len(nums) and more, but never worked.

Comment: Instead of the inner loop and the `> 0` test: `print(', '.join(num[i::-1]), 'and his dog...')`

Comment: are you sure of the capitalization and punctuation of your examples?

Answer (score 0):

Looping with indices is not usually necessary in Python. Try this:

```
for i, men in enumerate (num):
    menlist = ' '.join(num[i : : -1])
    print (men, ' went to mow, went to mow a meadow ', menlist, 'and his dog went to move a meadow')
```

Comment: thank you! unfortunately though, my teacher only wants us to use 'stuff we've learnt in lesson so far' which are pretty much everything basic like lists, for loops, while loops, if statements, etc

Comment: That's fine. But as you move forward you will mostly avoid looping with index counting. My code just says go through num list and get an item and it's place in the list, then make a string from the num list starting from the current place going back to the start, then print everything out - item, string and the connecting text; then repeat with next item until finished. You could code this just with for loops. As it is homework you'll learn more by doing it yourself.

Comment: I have another suggestion. When you write some code paste it into https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit and visualize it working, You can step through and watch how variables change and so on. It also has examples you can try out. If your code has errors then this approach might help fix it.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to try to define the structure, capitalization and pluralization in distinct functional bits, instead of a hardcoded list of partial phrases. This makes for slightly more generalizable code. Later, you could even import and use [`inflect`](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/) for larger numbers (and for pluralization of other words too, if needed).

**Edit**: defining a `line(n)` function:

```py
num = 'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten'.split()
trailing = ' went to mow a meadow.'

def mm(n):
    return 'man' if n < 2 else 'men'

def line(n):
    i = n - 1
    part1 = f'{num[i]} {mm(i+1)} went to mow,{trailing}'.capitalize()
    part2 = ', '.join(reversed(
        [f'{word} {mm(j+1)}{" and his dog" if j==0 else ""}'
         for j, word in enumerate(num[:i+1])])).capitalize()
    part2 += trailing
    line = ' '.join([part1, part2])
    return line
```

Example:

```py
>>> line(3)
'Three men went to mow, went to mow a meadow. Three men, two men, one man and his dog went to mow a meadow.'
```

To produce the whole nursery rhyme:

```py
for n in range(1, len(num)+1):
    print(line(n))
```

Produces:

```
One man went to mow, went to mow a meadow. One man and his dog went to mow a meadow.
Two men went to mow, went to mow a meadow. Two men, one man and his dog went to mow a meadow.
Three men went to mow, went to mow a meadow. Three men, two men, one man and his dog went to mow a meadow.
...
Ten men went to mow, went to mow a meadow. Ten men, nine men, eight men, seven men, six men, five men, four men, three men, two men, one man and his dog went to mow a meadow.
```

Comment: this isnt what i want, i want lets say "three men went to mow, went to mow the meadow, three men two men one man and his dog, went to mow the meadow" all working with any amount

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Do you mean, you'd like a function that produces a line given `n`? E.g. `f(2) == 'Two men went to mow, went to mow a meadow. Two men, one man and his dog went to mow a meadow.'`? It is very easy to do given the code above.